# How to Implement ViewController custom init using dependency injection and factory patterns?

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, factory

I am trying to implement simple example using DI and factory.

`ViewController.swift`

```
class VIewController : UIViewController {
    private let factory: ViewControllerFactory

    init(with factory: Factory) {
        self.factory = factory
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
}

protocol ViewControllerFactory {
    func makeViewController() -> ViewController

}

class DependencyContainer {
   /// 
}

extension DependencyContainer: ViewControllerFactory {
    func makeViewController() -> ViewController {
        return ViewController(with: self)

    }
}
```

`AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
    [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let container = DependencyContainer()
    let rootViewController = container.makeViewController()

    self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

I have view controller designed in storyboard. How I can I correct my code to run app successfully?

App is crashing:

- I am removing storyboard entry point from view controller, but the outlets are nil and it is crashing when I am using them.
- initWithCoder is calling in case when I don't remove that entry point from storyboard.

Comment: indeed, it's kind of "not how storyboards work" as Josh explains.  Learn everything about init#withCoder !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different types of dependency injection. You're currently trying to use constructor-based dependency injection, which unfortunately doesn't really work with storyboards, since they need to initialise with a decoder. iOS 13 does introduce some additional functionality which will make this approach possible, but for the moment, you could use setter-based dependency injection instead.

Something like the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var factory: ViewControllerFactory!
}

protocol ViewControllerFactory {
    func makeViewController() -> ViewController
}

class DependencyContainer {
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: Bundle.main)
}

extension DependencyContainer: ViewControllerFactory {
    func makeViewController() -> ViewController {
        guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController else {
            fatalError("Unrecognised viewController")
        }
        vc.factory = self
        return vc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are describing is how storyboards work (ie they call `initWithCoder`).  If you need your constructor to be called you can use a nib file then call your constructor which calls `init(nibName:bundle:)` and will correctly load the nib file.  This works on current iOS versions.

The only way to get constructor injection with a storyboard is to use iOS 13 and use the new `@IBSegueAction` which will give you a coder that you can pass into your constructor and then call super `initWithCoder`.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 13, you can initialise a storyboard view controller as follows:

Add an initialiser to your `ViewController` class

```
let property: Property // Your injected property

required init?(coder: NSCoder, property: Property) {
    self. property = property
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) { // You'll need to add this 
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

In your factory class:

```
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController") { coder in
    ViewController(coder: coder, property: <injected property>)
}
```